# Error: Core Data Code generation is not supported for Swift 2.3

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm getting the error:

```
Core Data Code generation is not supported for Swift 2.3
```

since I moved to Swift 2.3 but I cannot find any documentation or previous questions about this issue. Is CoreData not available in Swift 2.3?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code generation for Core Data is not available for Swift 2.3 as the error states (as of Xcode 8 Beta 2).

Just create your entity classes and your @NSManaged attributes yourself.

In XCode Model Editor you'll find an option in the **Data Model Inspector** to disable automatic code generation (**Class -> CodeGen -> Manual/None**).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what it meant by "Code Generation". Wonder why they left "Create NSManagedObject Subclass.." option, if its not supported...

Answer (score 5):

In XCode Model Editor you'll find an option in the Data Model Inspector to disable automatic code generation (Class -> CodeGen -> Manual/None)
For more detail [Here](https://medium.com/@rajeshkumarlingavel/core-data-code-generation-is-not-supported-for-swift-2-3-3eef4e5b8514#.6efb5s9ha) is work around.

[image]