# Core Data code generation is not supported for Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8, swift2

I am using CoreData in my application. I was using it in Xcode 8 before it works fine but suddenly its throwing me this error. I tried searching for answer but not getting anything and took a look at a [Error: Core Data Code generation is not supported for Swift 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647987/error-core-data-code-generation-is-not-supported-for-swift-2-3) this answer but not solved my problem. If anyone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Data Model Inspector change the Module to **Current Product Module** and Codegen to **Manual/None**. This solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks. Clean and Build was required in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Codegen` to `Manual/None` in Utilities area for your `Model.xcdatamodeld` file.

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened still showing that error.

Comment: you may also need to to just to build so Xcode catches the change

Comment: I did that several times cleaning and building again and again.But no result.